# Unable to connect Power BI to Azure SQL DB

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database, powerbi-desktop, data-connections

1. I am using a service account (AD account sync’d with Azure AD) to connect to Azure SQL DB (Note: SQL account connection works but need AD account to work)
2. Service account (abc@xyz.com) has ‘Read/Write’ access on Azure SQL DB
3. Service account connection works from (SQL studio) SSMS.

I am getting "Microsoft SQL: Cannot open server '@xyz.com' requested by the login. The login failed" error. I don't understand what I am I doing wrong here. The account has been created in DB, it has access and still it doesn't connect.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please turn "Allow azure services and resources to access this server" setting to "Yes" and let me know if it works for you.
Follow the path: SQL Server -> Security -> Firewall and virtual networks -> Allow azure services and resources to access this server -> Yes.
Also make sure that your IP address is whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

That server name is too short to be an Azure SQL Database.

It should be something like `name.database.windows.net`

Comment: I do have the server that follows name.database.windows.net. Still it throws same error.

Comment: It looks too short to me https://snipboard.io/m7t6V4.jpg

Comment: Made a change - I was trying to use Database authentication so far and getting login failed error. I switched the authentication mode to 'Windows'. Now, I am getting a new error message.  [Error Details: "Microsoft SQL: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)"]. Is this Firewall related? If so, what needs to be enabled?

Comment: Try to connect to the same database through SSMS form the same machine. Let  me know

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the connection works from SSMS.